# How does device receive Android GCM push notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, server-push

I've been digging into android push notifications recently. I guess, I understood the overall architecture and message flow.

I imagine it like this:

```
[Own server] --> [GCM] --> [Device] --> [Application]
```

The only mysterious part of the route is between [GCM] and [Device].

Long story short, **what infrastructure is used to deliver message from [GCM] to [Device]?**

I've read somewhere a bit, that probably, device keeps an opened connection to the GCM. If this is the case, what kind of connection is open?

Comment: I think it uses [Gtalk connection](http://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2010/06/28/a-peek-inside-the-gtalkservice-connection). Not sure of ios but blackberry push works just like sms

Comment: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/03/introducing-blackberry-push-services-to-developers/

Comment: In BlackBerry: `[Own server] -> [Push Proxy Gateway (RIM BIS or corporate BES)] -> [carrier wireless network] -> [Device] -> [listener App]`. More info here: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=Push+Service

Comment: This is a distinct question for each platform: Android, iOS, BlackBerry.  Let's not mix it all up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the CGM there are a lot of informations on the [Android Developers center](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/adv.html).
The device keeps a connection open to the CGM (I think IP). If there is no connection between the server and the device, the CGM will store the incoming messages to deliver them later.

The iOS push technology keeps an IP connection open between the APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) and the device (cf: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service)). So it could be sensibly the same thing as the GCM.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. Wiki says exactly that. I just wonder, what kind of IP connection is this? Sort of TCP Socket connection? I guess, keeping an open connection could cause battery issues..?

Comment: I don't find anything about the CGM but for the APNS I found this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3. It seems to be a streaming TCP connection using a binary protocol.