# XMPP Notfication service instead of GCM / APNS

Tags: client, xmpp, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

[How does device receive Android GCM push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295674/how-does-device-receive-android-gcm-push-notification)

Hi,

In the link above the steps of GCM and Blackberry notifcation services are explained.

I'm wondering if it is possible to change the GCM (android) / APNS (iOS) to one central notfication service with XMPP? This because I want to build a server and client with XMPP and want to communicate between these as well with messages and notifications.

Thereby, with the setup of a webview in a android application and GCM sending notifications to the device, GCM is not reliable. Not all messages are send to the device. I'm not sure yet how this works for APNS, but the app will be used on different platforms and it would be nice if there is just one way of sending notifications.

Anybody experience with this? Or is there another way of implementing the notifcations?

Comment: What makes you think GCM is unreliable? GCM is itself using XMPP, but in a shared/enhanced way which is much more efficient than having several proprietary long-polling connections in place. If you have any doubts as to the reliability of GCM, keep in mind that it is used for all the Google services, for example Gmail and Play.

Answer (score 3):

iOS does not allow you to run apps in background (except of voice apps). This means that you cannot have a XMPP stream in the background with iOS. For iOS there is no other solution than APNS if you are not a voice app. Android does not have these restrictions. Windows Phone 7.X hast the same restrictions as iOS, I don't know how Blackberry handles this.